# what does string - '0' do (string is a char)

Tags: c, string, char

what does this do

```
while(*string) {
    i = (i << 3) + (i<<1) + (*string -'0');
    string++;
}
```

the *string -'0'

does it remove the character value or something?

Comment: Compilers can optimize...why do people think they need to do `(i<<3)+(i<<1)` for `i*10`??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This subtracts from the character to which `string` is pointing the ASCII code of the character `'0'`. So, `'0'` - `'0'` gives you `0` and so on and `'9'` - `'0'` gives you `9`.

The entire loop is basically calculating "manually" the numerical value of the decimal integer in the string `string` points to.

That's because `i << 3` is equivalent to `i * 8` and `i << 1` is equivalent to `i * 2` and `(i << 3) + (i<<1)` is equivalent to `i * 8 + i * 2` or `i * 10`.

Answer (score 3):

Since the digits 0-9 are guaranteed to be stored contiguously in the character set, subtracting `'0'` gives the integer value of whichever character digit you have.

Let's say you're using ASCII:

```
char digit = '6'; //value of 54 in ASCII
int actual = digit - '0'; //'0' is 48 in ASCII, therefore `actual` is 6.
```

No matter which values the digits have in the character set, since they're contiguous, subtracting the beginning (`'0'`) from the digit will give the digit you're looking for. Note that the same is NOT particularly true for the letters. Look at EBCDIC, for example.

Comment: Very useful. This helped me better than accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It converts the ascii value of 0-9 characters to its numerical value.

ASCII value of '0' (character) is 48 and '1' is 49. 
So to convert 48-56('0'-'9') to  0-9, you just need to subtract 48 from the ascii value. 
that is what your code line [ *string -'0' ] is doing.