# Vector storing int as ascii code

Tags: c++, csv, vector, ascii

I have started writing a code that takes a CSV file and store any numerical numbers found into a vector.

This works great apart from the fact that instead of storing the number as read, it is storing the ascii code of the read character.

For example instead of storing the number 9 it is storing the number 57.

I have shown the respective part of my code below:

```
std::vector< int > buffer;

if(isdigit(fileLine[inCol])){
    buffer.push_back(fileLine[inCol]);
}
```

When I am later using `std::cout` to output an item in the vector, I would like to see the value not the ascii code. Can someone help me out here?

Thanks

Comment: Store them in a `vector<char>`?

Comment: they must be held as int for mathematical ease

Comment: Character codes are not the numbers those codes represent. You need to convert them. Perhaps as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927087/what-does-string-0-do-string-is-a-char)

Comment: Then cast them to `char` when printing them.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid `0 - 13 = #`

Comment: @Rhys, Then read integers from the file instead of characters. 13 won't be stored properly if you read a single 1 and then a single 3 and you want it to be 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract from `'0'` to get the conversion to `int`:

```
buffer.push_back(fileLine[inCol] - '0');
//                               ^^^^^
```

Comment: Perfect! that seems to be what I'm looking for. Will accept in 8 minutes when it will let me!

Answer (score 0):

It's storing the number as an int because you told it to when you said

vector<int>....

If you say

vector<char>

it will store them as characters.

Answer (score 0):

I can guess that `fileLine` has type `std::string` or os some char array. in this case the value of expression

```
fileLine[inCol]
```

is the ASCII code of the corresponding character.

You should write

```
if(isdigit(fileLine[inCol])){
    buffer.push_back(fileLine[inCol] - '0' );
}
```