# What does subtracting by char 0 do?

Tags: c#

On [this page](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Luhn_test_of_credit_card_numbers#C.23), the sample code for C# contains the following code, where cardNumber is a string:

`cardNumber.Select(c => c - '0').ToArray()`

Now, what this appears to do is subtract 0 from each char in cardNumber, returning each as ints, then put them into an array. My questions, specifically about the `c - '0'` part of this code are:

1) Why does it do this? What is the underlying behavior/explanation?

2) Why would this be done instead of using Int32.Parse?

Note: [Here is a similar question in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927087/what-does-string-0-do-string-is-a-char), this question may have the same/similar explanation.

Comment: Yes the answer is the same as in that other question. This appears to be a trick someone thought up to quickly split up a numeric string into individual digits in a single line of code.

Comment: And this is an elegant code. Int32.Parse would seem more complex.

Comment: The other question does not explain the benefits of using this method in C#, however.

Comment: I think using Int32.Parse would be more readable.

Comment: Also, parsing takes more time than subtraction.

Comment: this is simple. look value of `'0'` is `48`. then `49` is `'1'` so `49-48 = 1`. and so on. its faster than Int32.Parse

Comment: @JamesG. Yes, `Int32.Parse` is more clear. However, if you can make a number of assumptions about the input, this code is more efficient and direct.

Comment: for a programmer both `c - '0'` and `int.Parse(c)` should be readable!

Comment: For what it's worth I would have added a comment to this line. And probably would have just subtracted `48` instead of `'0'`.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary that is strange suggestion - one compiles just fine, another does not... Readability is subjective, but ability to compile/correctness is important too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's subtracting unicode code points. So if `c` was something like `9` the operation is  `'9' - '0'`. The code point for `9` is `57` and `0` is `48`, so it will perform `57 - 48` which results in `9`.

The only reason I can think of doing this over an `int.Parse` would be speed - this is an arithmetic operation which is much faster than whatever `int.Parse` does.

Comment: Unicode code points, in the general case of subtracting `char`s. Which are indeed equal to ASCII for `'0'`...`'9'`. (Even that isn't 100% accurate, but it is a lot closer.)

Comment: @hvd yes, thanks. C# internally uses UTF-16 so that's more correct.

Comment: Good answer. Hope you don't mind me linking to your explanation in my answer, but I wanted to explain one of the gotchas with this approach, and you already covered the _what do it do_ part comprehensively.  If you would prefer that I didn't link to you, let me know and I'll write up my own explanation.

Comment: You will have to convert char to string to use Parse - will look way more confusing than somewhat traditional `c - '0'` to get digit... If you want to get readability points - use `Char.GetNumericValue`.

Answer (score 1):

Each character has a numerical representation so it can be stored in memory, and the `c - '0'` operation is simply subtracting the number that represents `'0'` from the number that represents the character held by `c`.

Hence, if `c` holds `'5'` the result of the operation will be the number `5`.

Here is quick refrence to the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) printable code chart, to which [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) is backward compatible:

```
Binary      Oct Dec Hex Glyph

010 0000    040 32  20  (space)
010 0001    041 33  21  !
010 0010    042 34  22  "
010 0011    043 35  23  #
010 0100    044 36  24  $
010 0101    045 37  25  %
010 0110    046 38  26  &
010 0111    047 39  27  '
010 1000    050 40  28  (
010 1001    051 41  29  )
010 1010    052 42  2A  *
010 1011    053 43  2B  +
010 1100    054 44  2C  ,
010 1101    055 45  2D  -
010 1110    056 46  2E  .
010 1111    057 47  2F  /
011 0000    060 48  30  0
011 0001    061 49  31  1
011 0010    062 50  32  2
011 0011    063 51  33  3
011 0100    064 52  34  4
011 0101    065 53  35  5
011 0110    066 54  36  6
011 0111    067 55  37  7
011 1000    070 56  38  8
011 1001    071 57  39  9
011 1010    072 58  3A  :
011 1011    073 59  3B  ;
011 1100    074 60  3C  <
011 1101    075 61  3D  =
011 1110    076 62  3E  >
011 1111    077 63  3F  ?
100 0000    100 64  40  @
100 0001    101 65  41  A
100 0010    102 66  42  B
100 0011    103 67  43  C
100 0100    104 68  44  D
100 0101    105 69  45  E
100 0110    106 70  46  F
100 0111    107 71  47  G
100 1000    110 72  48  H
100 1001    111 73  49  I
100 1010    112 74  4A  J
100 1011    113 75  4B  K
100 1100    114 76  4C  L
100 1101    115 77  4D  M
100 1110    116 78  4E  N
100 1111    117 79  4F  O
101 0000    120 80  50  P
101 0001    121 81  51  Q
101 0010    122 82  52  R
101 0011    123 83  53  S
101 0100    124 84  54  T
101 0101    125 85  55  U
101 0110    126 86  56  V
101 0111    127 87  57  W
101 1000    130 88  58  X
101 1001    131 89  59  Y
101 1010    132 90  5A  Z
101 1011    133 91  5B  [
101 1100    134 92  5C  \
101 1101    135 93  5D  ]
101 1110    136 94  5E  ^
101 1111    137 95  5F  _
110 0000    140 96  60  `
110 0001    141 97  61  a
110 0010    142 98  62  b
110 0011    143 99  63  c
110 0100    144 100 64  d
110 0101    145 101 65  e
110 0110    146 102 66  f
110 0111    147 103 67  g
110 1000    150 104 68  h
110 1001    151 105 69  i
110 1010    152 106 6A  j
110 1011    153 107 6B  k
110 1100    154 108 6C  l
110 1101    155 109 6D  m
110 1110    156 110 6E  n
110 1111    157 111 6F  o
111 0000    160 112 70  p
111 0001    161 113 71  q
111 0010    162 114 72  r
111 0011    163 115 73  s
111 0100    164 116 74  t
111 0101    165 117 75  u
111 0110    166 118 76  v
111 0111    167 119 77  w
111 1000    170 120 78  x
111 1001    171 121 79  y
111 1010    172 122 7A  z
111 1011    173 123 7B  {
111 1100    174 124 7C  |
111 1101    175 125 7D  }
111 1110    176 126 7E  ~
```

Comment: No problem, since it's fixed, I've cleaned up the comment. This one will self destruct within 12 hours.

Answer (score 1):

What Dave Zych points out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33159575/5240004) is absolutely correct. This converts a string into an array of digits.

You often will see things like this done on embedded systems where parsing an `int` is an expensive operation.  There is one significant flaw with this approach. *(Other than that it's not immediately obvious to the uninitiated what it does.)*

Consider what happens with the following input string:

```
اختبار
```

The resulting array comes out to

```
{ 1527, 1534, 1530, 1528, 1527, 1537 }
```

The failure when using this method is silent because `اختبار` is as valid a string as `123456`. Using `int.Parse`, while it may be slower, will throw a `FormatException` to let you know that something went wrong.

While it is certainly acceptable in some cases to use the `c - '0'` method, just be sure when using it that you understand the risks, and make sure to test edge cases.

*(For anyone who's interested the Arabic is 'test' translated using Google Translate)*